# Combining output of two machines

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Two machine are making some products, with machine $1$ producing twice as many items as the machine 2.

However, about $4\%$ of the items from the machine $1$ and about $2\%$ items from the machine $2$ are defective.

Suppose that the daily output of the two machines is combined. A random 
sample of $10$ is taken from the combined output. What is the probability that
this sample contains $2$ defectives?

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @vedran if it is only one machine provided then i know how to do...
but it was given that two machines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in any given sample, $2/3$ of all products were produced by the first machine, and $4\%$ of those are defective. The remaining $1/3$ products were produced by the second machine, and $2\%$ of those are defective.

So, the overall number of defective products is

$$\frac{2}{3} \cdot 4\% + \frac{1}{3} \cdot 2\% = \frac{10\%}{3} = \frac{1}{30}.$$

You can now handle this as if it was a single machine with $1/30$ defects.

**How did I get $2/3?** (requested in the comments)

If the first machine produces $x$ items, and the second one produces $y$, and we have that the first produces two times more than the second, then

$$x = 2y.$$

So, out of all the items ($x+y$), the first one produces

$$\frac{x}{x+y} = \frac{2y}{2y+y} = \frac{2y}{3y} = \frac{2}{3} \text{of them}.$$

Analogously, the second machine produces $\frac{y}{x+y} = \frac{y}{3y} = \frac{1}{3}$ of all the items.

Comment: can u please explain how 2/3 of all products were produced by the first machine??

Comment: @anshul22 See my edit. I hope this makes it clear.